# Readdir и русские наименования

Tags: readdir, c++, кириллица

Здравствуйте, столкнулся со следующей проблемой

```
if((dir = opendir (data)) != NULL){
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL){
    cout << ent->d_name << endl;
  }
  closedir (dir);
}
```

Выводит русские наименования файлов/папок в таком формате: 
C5DF~1.TXT, 3E92~1.LS, 1F15~1.BAT

Как это исправить и вывести нормальное название файла?

Comment: Хм. А какой компилятор? Если что-нибудь древнее под DOS, неудивительно.

Comment: @VladD, VS2012

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я спрашивал как быть с opendir - readdir, вы же предлагаете совершенно другую реализацию.

Comment: @Kenpachi как я понял, комментарий @Yura Ivanov даёт однозначный ответ на Ваш вопрос про opendir - readdir -- забить. Слава MS!

Comment: @alexlz в таком случае то не ответ, а оффтоп т.к мой вопрос касается получения полного имени через opendir - readdir.

Comment: Видимо Вам придется добавить ещё вызов одной функции, которая будет расшифровывать короткие имена в длинные.

И кстати, то, что выводит функция - вполне нормальные имена (для этой функции).